# Creating a string of digits in javascript each within a limit

Tags: javascript

How can I use javascript to randomly create a 20 digit string of numbers, each of the digits ranging only between 1 and 5?

An example would be: 52431425331425141521

Comment: Pick a random number between 1 and 5. Then pick another. And another. And so on. Join them all together. Done!

Comment: Do you know how to get a random number between 1 and 5? Do it 20 times in a loop and concatenate them.

Comment: You have already done it in your question: 52431425331425141521

Comment: I am unsure why my question was downvoted when it made sense to at least two contributors. How did I ask poorly? I added the word javascript in the question, but wasn't the tag enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
function random_string()
    {
        var text = "";
        var string = "12345";

        for( var i=0; i < 20; i++ )
            text += string.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * string.length));

        return text;
    }
    random_string();
```

Answer (score 3):

As well as the logical algorithm I gave in my comment above, you could just use this one-liner:

```
var result = Math.floor(Math.random()*95367431640625).toString(5)
                            .split("").map(function(n) {return +n+1;}).join("");
```

Essentially, pick a random integer between 0 and 5<sup>20</sup>-1, convert it to base 5, then increment all the digits by one, so they're all between 1 and 5 ^_^

EDIT: Just realised this won't handle low numbers too well. Try this:

```
var result = (
         new Array(20).join("0")
         +
         Math.floor(Math.random()*95367431640625).toString(5)
     ).slice(-20).split("").map(function(n) {return +n+1;}).join(""));
```

This does basically the same, except it prepends 19 zeroes to the front of your number, then slices off the last 20 characters. This will allow it to handle leading zeroes correctly to give a 20-digit number in all cases.

Comment: I will definitely use the ideas you have included in your answer.